# Restart native app after crash

Tags: android, nativeapplication

In android 4.4 and below, who loads a native application `(/system/bin/*)` at startup, I think that the file init.rc is responsible, it is correct?

Then if a native application crashes (for example `/system/bin/mediaserver`) it restart automatically, then the question is: who is responsible for the application restart? there is a file?

Answer (score 0):

> ActivityManagerService restarts the native apps.

There's usually some chatter in `logcat` when an app is restarted by the `activity manager service`, in the normal log and/or event log

```
(logcat -b events).
```

> **More Info:**

If you see the code of [ActivityManagerService.finishForceStopPackageLocked()](http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#5884) method, this method fires an Intent with action `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED`.

And it is called from various methods like:
 
[ActivityManagerService.forceStopPackage()](http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#5650)
[IPackageDataObserveronRemoveCompleted.onRemoveCompleted()](http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#5470)

So internally there's an `PackageDataObserver` implemented in `ActivityManagerService`, which observes if any package is removed, and if it's need to be restarted, an intent is fired with the action `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED`

And every package is forced closed using `ActivityManagerService.forceStopPackage()`, it knows which package to restart.

Hope it clears the doubt.

Comment: Sorry, I see nothing from logcat, I see only a crash of /system/bin/mediaserver, but I don't see the restart of mediaserver with another pid